# wget extract text and save to file

Tags: linux, wget

So I have several json files I need to go through and extract email addresses from. They are formatted like this. %40 being the @ symbol.

```
"email":"google%40gmail.com"
```

I am using wget to grab all my files, but they have much more content inside that I do not need right now. What would be the best way to modify this script below to just grab the email like above?

```
for i in $(seq 0 1000); do wget "http://example./com/users.php?info=user/user.json&user_id=${i}" --output-document="${i}.txt"; done
```

Comment: Use `curl` instead of `wget` and pipe the data to [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/).

Comment: Not very familiar with that. Have any examples? Thanks

Comment: An example would require an example JSON file.